# Trigger an event only if it is outside of a dom element that has a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have an event listener that listens to clicks. If these clicks are outside of a given dom element, a certain function is called (in this case, `handleClick`).

Right now, the function `handleClick` is only called if the event target is not the one that has the `this.setWrapper` ref.

I am wondering how I can prevent `handleClick` from being called if I also happen to click on `.boxTwo`.

Note, I want to do this not by adding a ref to the div of `.boxTwo`, but by querying to DOM to identify any clicks that happen inside of the div that has the class name 'boxTwo'. Thanks!

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {onClick: false};
    this.setWrapperRef = this.setWrapperRef.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick);
  }

  setWrapperRef(node) {
    this.wrapperRef = node;
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target)) {
      this.setState({onClick: !this.state.onClick});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <div className="boxOne" ref={this.setWrapperRef} />
        <div className="boxTwo" />
        <div>{this.state.onClick ? "On" : "Off"}</div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.boxOne {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.boxTwo {
  margin: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  border: solid black 2px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You just need to check if `event.target.className` does not equal `boxTwo`, like this snippet below.
- You may use the same "technique" to prevent your function from being called if the target has a `boxOne` class.
- If you want to trigger in all cases where there is no className at all, you may use just this in your conditional statement: `!event.target.className`

A little extra, I would have done it this way for the sake of readability

```js
handleClick(event) {

    // The ones that don't trigger
    const disabledTriggers = ['boxOne', 'boxTwo'];

    // Ok if no class contained in our event classList are disabled
    const ok = !disabledTriggers.some(c => event.target.classList && event.target.classList.contains(c))
    if(ok) {
      this.setState({onClick: !this.state.onClick});
    }
  }
```

And here's your snippet with the solution and the least modifications.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {onClick: false};
    this.setWrapperRef = this.setWrapperRef.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick);
  }

  setWrapperRef(node) {
    this.wrapperRef = node;
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    
    if (event.target.className !== 'boxTwo' && this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target)) {
      this.setState({onClick: !this.state.onClick});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <div className="boxOne" ref={this.setWrapperRef} />
        <div className="boxTwo" />
        <div>{this.state.onClick ? "On" : "Off"}</div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.boxOne {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.boxTwo {
  margin: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  border: solid black 2px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain what I have done.

1. Added one state to maintain the classes for the elements on which
   we don't want to have onclick.
2. Added one more container class to the boxOne class to check that this holds true even if we have more than one class.
3. I have check that `event.target.classList`(which returns the list of the class current target have) and check that anyone from the classList exists to the state wrapperRefs.
4. If it does not exists then it is click outside the component. I hope this
   helps you.

   If you have any doubt comment below. I would like to help you as much as I can.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {onClick: false, wrapperRefs: ['boxOne', 'boxTwo']};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    const classes = event.target.classList;
    const exists = this.state.wrapperRefs.some(ref => classes.contains(ref));
    if(!exists) {
      this.setState({onClick: !this.state.onClick});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <div className="boxOne container" />
        <div className="boxTwo" />
        <div>{this.state.onClick ? "On" : "Off"}</div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.boxOne {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.boxTwo {
  margin: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  border: solid black 2px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```